# Change Netbeans default project folder to something other than nbproject

Tags: netbeans-7, collaboration

We have multiple people working on php projects. Is there a way to have netbeans 7.2 call the folder with all the metadata something other than nbproject?

I want all projects I create from existing sources to have something like qwertymk and whenever I create projects or try to load them it will always go to folder named qwertymk instead of nbproject.

Comment: Why can't you all share the same project metadata?

Comment: More information is required.  Are they separate PHP projects?  Multiple developers working on the same project?  If the later, and all using netbeans, netbean property files can be edited to use relative pathnames, eliminating the fullpath problem.  I've done this for two netbeans projects (one with 6 the other 7) that are part of a larger project that is NOT maintained via netbeans.  It helps to being familiar with Ant when doing such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the folder name is hardcoded in several places within Netbeans, but you have options to work around that by placing the nbproject somewhere else, e.g. into a subfoler where it does not get on your nerves. Look at this old thread, specifically at [this post](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Rename-nbproject-netbeans-folder-tp2980198p2980215.html). I cannot magically change hardcoded Netbeans stuff for you, but I would be happy if the solution I am pointing you to would satisfy your needs and answer the question.

Comment: Well there always is hacking NetBeans itself like greping through the compiled code to change all occurences or something like that

Comment: Feel free to do that if you do not like my suggestion. Have you tried it at all?

Comment: What do you mean? You did not manage to put the nbproject folder to another location based on the description, or it was just not an acceptable workaround for your work environment?

Comment: Works fine with NetBeans 7.1.2. Just make a directory for each developer in your current project path (say, `prj/john`), then create a separate NetBeans project inside it (`prj/john/nbproject`) inside each one and change the `src.dir=.` in `prj/john/nbproject/project.properties` files to `src.dir=..`.